# Javascript text input clear button stops working in Bootstrap when I add my css. Any advice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've a piece of code that's been working fine until I include some css.

Here is the link to the code (the code editor here didn't like the mix of script and html and was testing my patience sorry). 
[Gist code snippet can be viewed here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/343c69f2aff1720e030f)

It's using Bootstrap.  The issue is this works fine (it displays a text input with a x to clear it and when you press the x it clears the text input box).  When I include the...

```
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

though, clicking the `x` in the input box does nothing.  Can anyone see any obvious reasons?

Without CSS included it's fine.  With CSS included it fails.

The css file is basically a massive compiles .less file and probably not appropriate to place in a code box here so [here it is in another gist link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/eca809fdb7e9bcb68fd8).

UPDATE:  Here are the console logs if that helps:  [enter link description here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/efffcef0629f2c13c9c2)

Comment: CSS shouldn't have an effect on behavior like that. Are you seeing console errors? Do you have something you can post for us to look at?

Comment: Strip out every line from the CSS file. Add them back in until you find the rules that cause the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: These are the console logs if that helps? https://gist.github.com/anonymous/efffcef0629f2c13c9c2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The locations of your javascript file links and event handler code are incorrect. You are calling `$("#searchclear").click(.....` before you load jQuery and all of the linked js files should be just before the closing `body` tag, not after it. Changing your `html` to the below will fix this issue:

### [Working Demo](http://dodsoftware.com/sotests/css-error/index.html)

(note that I changed some of the links to link to the CDN versions of the files to avoid errors in my demo):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 9 ]><html class="ie9"><![endif]-->

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>create appt</title>

<!-- Vendor CSS -->
<link href="vendors/animate-css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- CSS -->
<link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Following CSS codes are used only for specifics in this test-->
<style type="text/css">
.margin-bottom > * {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#searchclear {
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 14px;
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 14px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #ccc;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="btn-group">
  <input id="searchinput" type="search" class="form-control" value="LUNCH">
  <span id="searchclear" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span> </div>

<!-- Javascript Libraries --> 
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script src="vendors/nicescroll/jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script> 
<script src="vendors/waves/waves.min.js"></script> 
<script src="vendors/bootstrap-growl/bootstrap-growl.min.js"></script> 
<script src="vendors/bootstrap-wizard/jquery.bootstrap.wizard.min.js"></script> 
<script src="vendors/sweet-alert/sweet-alert.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/functions.js"></script> 
<script>
$("#searchclear").click(function(){
    $("#searchinput").val('');
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That did it!  Now you've said it, it makes complete sense.  I really want to thank you. I wasted too many hours on this today.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

```
<!-- css -->
<link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I was pretty excited thinking it could be so simple but that didn't change anything.  I do appreciate you taking the time though.

Comment: Welcome. Are you chacked css path?

Comment: Yes, the CSS definitely loads.  The styling is all in place with it loaded and with it commented out the styling is gone.  When it is loaded though, the input clearing X does not work.  When it's not loaded, it does work.  Crazy.